# Django-rest-framework Details View and corresponding URL for Model with two non-nested foreign keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm creating a REST API with Django-rest-framework.

I have a Users model, a Spots model and a UserSpots model. The Users model and Spots models are very simple. The UserSpots model represents Users following Spots. The UserSpots model is defined by the foreign keys of the Users and Spots models. However, the Spots model is not necessarily nested within the Users model.  Users and Spots exist independently. Users cannot create Spots. There are Users that do not follow any Spots and there are Spots that have zero User followers.

I have successfully created Views to display:

- `SpotsListView` = list all spots

   `/spots/`
- `SpotsIndividualView` = retrieve single spot

  `/spots/(spotId)/`
- `UsersListView` = list all users

  `/users/`
- `UsersIndividualView` = retrieve/update single user

  `/users/(userId)/`
- `UserSpotsListView` = list all spots followed by single user

  `/users/(userId)/favspots/`

### The question:

**I cannot figure out how to write a view to create/retrieve/update/delete a single spot that a single user is following:**

- `UserSpotsIndividualView`

   `/users/(userId)/favspots/(spotId)/`

I've included the relevant pieces of my API below. I've tried dozens of different ways to create the UserSpotsIndividualView so I've encountered all sorts of different error messages. I'm ommitting the error messages as well as the majority of my attempts for conciseness.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#     HERE ARE MY MODELS     #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

class Users(AbstractUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # make the primary key "userId" instead of "id"
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # override default settings of username being used for authentication
    email = models.EmailField(ugettext_lazy('email address'), unique=True)
    unitId = models.IntegerField(default=1)  # default to US units
    birthYear = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    genderId = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # sets email field to be used for authentication
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.email)

 class Spots(models.Model):
    """This class represents the spots model."""
    spotId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    spotName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    areaId = models.IntegerField()
    latitude = models.FloatField(default=999.999)
    longitude = models.FloatField(default=999.999)

    def __str__(self):
        return self

 class UserSpots(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(Users, db_column='userId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    spotId = models.ForeignKey(Spots, db_column='spotId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    displayOrder = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('userId', 'spotId', 'displayOrder')
        ordering = ['displayOrder']

    def __str__(self):
        return self
```

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#     HERE ARE MY SERIALIZERS     #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Spots, Users, UserSpots

class SpotsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Spots
        fields = ('spotId', 'spotName', 'areaId')

class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('userId', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'unitId', 'birthYear', 'genderId')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}   # cannot query pw

class UserSpotsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserSpots
        fields = ('userId', 'spotId', 'displayOrder')
```

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#     HERE ARE MY VIEWS     #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Spots, Users, UserSpots
from .serializers import SpotsSerializer, UsersSerializer, UserSpotsSerializer

class SpotsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """This class lists all spots."""
    # renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,) #limit only to JSON - does not allow the browse-able api
    serializer_class = SpotsSerializer
    queryset = Spots.objects.all()

class SpotsIndividualView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """This class gets individual spots."""
    serializer_class = SpotsSerializer
    queryset = Spots.objects.all()

class UsersListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """This class lists all users."""
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    #permission_classes = (IsAdminList,)

class UsersIndividualView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """This class READs and UPDATES all individual users."""
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'userId'
    #permission_classes = (IsLoggedInUserOrAdmin,)

class UserSpotsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """This class lists all spots for a user by specifying the userId."""
    serializer_class = UserSpotsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        userId = self.kwargs['userId']
        return UserSpots.objects.filter(userId=userId)
```

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#     HERE IS THE VIEW I NEED HELP WITH     #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
class UserSpotsIndividualView():
    """ PLEASE HELP WITH THIS VIEW """
    return what_I_want


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#     HERE ARE A COUPLE OF MY ATTEMPTS     #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

class UserSpotsIndividualView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """This class should READ, UPDATE and DELETE individual spots for users."""
    serializer_class = UserSpotsSerializer
    #queryset = UserSpots.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'userSpot'

    def get_queryset(self):
        userId = self.kwargs['userId']
        spotId = self.kwargs['spotId']
        return UserSpots2.objects.filter(userSpot=userSpot, spotId=spotId)


from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class MultipleFieldLookupMixin(object):
    """
    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
    based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if self.kwargs[field]: # Ignore empty fields.
                filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

# Works with RetrieveAPIView but not with RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
class UserSpotsIndividualView(MultipleFieldLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """This class should READ, UPDATE and DELETE individual spots for users."""
    serializer_class = UserSpotsSerializer
    queryset = UserSpots.objects.all()
    lookup_fields = ('userId', 'spotId')
```

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
#     HERE ARE MY URLS     #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from .views import SpotsListView, SpotsIndividualView
from .views import UsersListView, UsersIndividualView
from .views import UserSpotsListView, UserSpotsIndividualView

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'spots/$', SpotsListView.as_view(), name="SpotsList"),
    url(r'spots/(?P<spotId>[0-9]+)/$', SpotsIndividualView.as_view(), name="SpotsDetails"),
    url(r'users/$', UsersListView.as_view(), name="UsersList"),
    url(r'users/(?P<userId>[0-9]+)/$', UsersIndividualView.as_view(), name="UsersDetails"),
    url(r'users/(?P<userId>[0-9]+)/favspot/$', UserSpotsListView.as_view(), name="UserSpotsList"),
    url(r'users/(?P<userId>[0-9]+)/favspot/(?P<spotId>[0-9]+)/$', UserSpotsIndividualView.as_view(), name="UserSpotsDetail"), # DOES NOT WORK

}

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```